# Does Jack's compass still work?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

The whole theme of "Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales" is breaking curses. And, basically; they succeed in doing so - they break *all* curses of the sea.

However, Jack's compass is most definitely magical in some way, but does carry a heavy warning:

> "Don't betray the compass..!"

This, to me, says that the compass does carry some kind of link to the plot of the movie - if you betray the compass, it will release your darkest fears.

So, after all of that, does Jacks compass still work the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Probably.

It's never explicitly confirmed to still work, but there's also little to no reason to think that it wouldn't.

The compass has been used for many different plotlines, and it has never been consumed by any plot. It is likely a standalone enchanted object, so it stands to reason that it doesn't stop working because the plotline it's connected to (e.g. a cursed opponent) ceases to exist.

---

> > "Don't betray the compass..!"
>
> This, to me, says that the compass does carry some kind of link to the plot of the movie - if you betray the compass, it will release your darkest fears.

I thought the movie made this abundantly clear. The exact *second* that Jack offers the compass up for bartering (thus betraying the compass), Salazar is released from the triangle and is suddenly free to roam the seas.

Salazar was Jack's biggest fear at the time.

---

**A small musing...**

I'd be interested to see what would've happened if Jack offered the compass for a trade in Dead Man's Chest. Since Davy Jones was Jack's main fear (due to their deal), would the compass have set Davy Jones loose on Jack?

In other words, was the compass exclusively linked to **Salazar**, or is it linked to **Jack** (as it's his compass now) and does it then release the biggest fear *specific to the **owner** who betrays the compass*?

Comment: I thought the Op's question wasn't the link to Salazar, but if the compass (or its consequence-laden fine print), counted as a "curse of the sea".  Maybe it is a standalone enchantment, since compasses don't *have* to be used at sea, but I could see why the question is asked since it mostly is in the movies.

Comment: In all honesty it makes sense if the one wielding it must not betray the compass (although it was given back to jack once.....without any negative effect).  The compass shows you to where the heart wants to be and releases the hearts fears if it feels betrayed.

Comment: @Thomas: About giving the compass away earlier (e.g. to Elizabeth who wants to find Will), you can argue that Jack is loaning the compass _to get what he wants_, which may be valid. Jack never really gave up the compass, he merely let  someone else use it (since their heart was pointing in a better direction than Jack's at the time). When he barters in DMTNT, he is giving the compass up.

Answer (score 1):

In the last scene of "Dead Men Tell No Tales", Jack looks at the compass and if I'm correct, it still does not point perpendicular to the shadow in it. Assuming it's sunset, that would mean it's not actually pointing North, so it still doesn't work. However, I would like to hear comments regarding whether or not it's pointing perpendicular to the shadow, as I'm not yet 100% sure about that part.

[image: screenshot of compass in Jack's hand]

Comment: This answer seems to be based on the belief that the compass "working" consists of it pointing North. That is not what the compass is for.